# Problems with JOSSO logout

Tags: josso

I have problem with JOSSO logout – I can’t logout after session-timeout expires. It just redirected to default home page. I increase session-timeout as suggested in http://www.atricore.org/jira/browse/JOSSO-70.  It helps, but it is not solution for me for security reasons. I'm using JOSSO 1.8.5. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

When you are logged in, can you provided the list of cookies that are set in you application relatively to JOSSO session ?

- should be one for each partner app
- and one for the gateway

Then have a look of the expiration of each cookie. This is the expiration date that might cause you trouble. Also, what kind of agent are you using ?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have check cookies, all cookies expire with session. What you mean with what kind of agent?

Comment: I mean agent on what app (Asp.NET, tomcat, etc.) ? So if cookie expires on session, check that the session on the client app is not longer than the session on the gateway